# lexical elements of grammar

Tags: grammar, lexical

There is 4 lexical elements of grammar

```
G = (S, N, T, P)
```

Where G = Grammar, S = Start Symbol, N = Non-Terminals, T = Terminals, P = Production rules

I wanted to know if N is always equal with P because as I know P are lexemes which may replace with other lexemes

So in this example:

```
<program> --> <stmts>
<stmts> --> <stmt> | <stmt> ; <stmts>
<stmt> --> <var> = <expr>
<var> --> a | b | c | d
<expr> --> <term> + <term> | <term> - <term>
<term> --> <var> | const

S: <program>
N: <program>, <stmts>, <var>, <expr>, <term>
T: ;, a, b, c, d, +, -, const
P: <program>, <stmts>, <var>, <expr>, <term>
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. |N| does not necessarily = |P|.  Consider:

```
<program> --> <stmts>
<stmts> --> <stmt> 
<stmts> -->| <stmt> ; <stmts>
<stmt> --> <var> = <expr>
<var> --> a 
<var> --> b
<var> --> c
<var> --> d
<expr> --> <term> + <term> 
<expr> --> <term> - <term>
<term> --> <var> 
<term> --> const
```

Your problem is that you are not precise about what is allowed in a grammar rule.

You can *force* the number of rules to match nonterminals, by insisting that no rule has the same left hand side.  To do that, you can't insist on simple BNF; you have to have extended BNF with at least alternation.

PS: This isn't really about "lexical elements" of a grammar.  It is just about the definition of a grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I remembered some things... So the P are 12, right?

Comment: For the grammar as I have provided, P==12 and N==6

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like homework... You have it basically right, only P **are the actual rules**.

```
G = (S, N, T, P)

S: <program>
N: <program>, <stmts>, <var>, <expr>, <term>
T: ;, a, b, c, d, +, -, const
P: <program> --> <stmts>, 
   <stmts> --> <stmt> | <stmt> ; <stmts>,
   <stmt> --> <var> = <expr>,
   <var> --> a | b | c | d,
   <expr> --> <term> + <term> | <term> - <term>,
   <term> --> <var> | const
```

Without rules the a grammar is useless.